# latexpdf-esque functionality in haskell?

Tags: linux, haskell, compilation, latex, pdflatex

My haskell program produces .tex output using my own module.
I can't see my way around having to run 'pdflatex' everytime I want to see a result. I can hardly believe this cannot be done in a more direct manner;

Is there a way to have my code compile the .tex-file?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can automate running TeX, or whether you can produce a PDF file without needing to use TeX?

Comment: I think I'm asking for the former. I have a haskell module that creates .tex-file output, and ideally I would have this module compile that file.

Comment: In that case, `System.Process` is the thing you're looking for. You can use it to run any external program - including TeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the `System.Process` package what you are looking for? You can use the function

```
system :: String -> IO ExitCode
```

to perform system calls.

```
$ touch tempfile.txt
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/   :? for help
>> import System.Process
>> system "ls"
tempfile.txt
ExitSuccess
```

Not particularly idiomatic, but it gets the job done.